# Ошибка при отправке файла через telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\dimon\Desktop\Yt Downloader Bot\main.py", line 31, in <module>
bot.polling()
File "C:\Users\dimon\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 658, in polling
self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
File "C:\Users\dimon\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 720, in __threaded_polling 
raise e
File "C:\Users\dimon\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 680, in __threaded_polling
self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
File "C:\Users\dimon\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
raise self.exception_info
File "C:\Users\dimon\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\dimon\Desktop\Yt Downloader Bot\main.py", line 28, in text_handler
video = open(r'C:\Users\dimon\Desktop\Yt Downloader Bot\temp\videos\Как обратить старение вспять? [Veritasium].mp4', 'rb')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\dimon\\Desktop\\Yt Downloader Bot\\temp\\videos\\Как обратить старение вспять? [Veritasium].mp4'
```

Код:

```
video = open(f'{PROJECT_FOLDER}\\temp\\videos\\{youtube.video.title}.mp4', 'rb')
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, video, filename = youtube.video.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
import os

video = open(os.path.join(PROJECT_FOLDER, 'temp', 'videos', youtube.video.title + ".mp4"), 'rb')
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, video, filename = youtube.video.title)
```

Comment: ту же ошибку выдает

Comment: Обновил, попробуйте ещё раз. И покажите переменную PROJECT_FOLDER, то как вы её обьявили

Comment: Убрал переменную project folder, та же ошибка. Код: video = open(os.path.join(Path.cwd(), 'temp', 'videos', youtube.video.title + ".mp4"), 'rb')

Comment: Вытащите путь в отдельную переменную, а сделайте принт

Comment: `path = os.path.join(Path.cwd(), 'temp', 'videos', youtube.video.title + ".mp4"`